# AJAX load function not working in IE10

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer-10

I have just finished my first AJAX request and got it working in Google, Safari Firefox ETC. It is very basic and just calls a PHP query with a random result and shows this inside a DIV. I then tested it in IE10 and the AJAX does not work. When i refresh teh page i get a new result but it does not refresh after 3 seconds. This is the code

```
$(function() {
    getStatus();
});

function getStatus() {
    $('div#status').load('thankyou.php')
    setTimeout("getStatus()",3000);
    setTimeout(function(){$("getstatus").html(getStatus)},3000);
}
```

I have looked for answers and got

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

between my head and head. It cured another issue i was having with a jquery rotator but not the AJAX. Is it my code or IE10? and any known soulutions?

Comment: what is `$("getstatus")` supposed to select?

Comment: Press "F12" on your keyboard and clear the cache, and chose "Always refresh from server" under the cache tab

Comment: DownMaster thanks, That worked for me. Any idea on how to get this working for other users?

Comment: `load('thankyou.php?12894189047190')` where the number is the timestamp might work for you

Comment: crush, Thanks, I think i understand the thought process but no didn't work on another computer. Will keep looking and update here if i find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Crush and DownMaster i looked at the problem in a different way. By preventing the AJAX page being cached seems to makes it work, adding `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` prevents the cache.

```
$(function() {
getStatus();
});
function getStatus() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });//prevents the AJAX cache.
$('div#status').load('thankyou.php')
setTimeout("getStatus()",3000);
setTimeout(function(){$("getstatus").html(getStatus)},3000);
}
```